# Hide specific root object during yaml serialization and show only it's children properties in yaml

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, deserialization, yamldotnet

I am using one object model

```
public class MainModel
{
 public FirstChildModel firstChild { get; set; }
 public SecondChildModel secondChild { get; set; }
}
public class FirstChildModel
{
 public string firstProp { get; set; }
 public string secondProp { get; set; }
}
public class SecondChildModel
{
 public string name { get; set; }
 public bool isValid { get; set; }
}
```

and I am getting it's respective yaml as

[image]

But is there any way so that i can hide specific root property and show it's respective children properties like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom type converter for this. The [documentation](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/wiki/Serialization.Deserializer#withtypeconverteriyamltypeconverter) shows how to register a type converter when building a serializer.

A custom type converter needs to implement [IYamlTypeConverter](https://github.com/aaubry/YamlDotNet/blob/master/YamlDotNet/Serialization/IYamlTypeConverter.cs). In your case, implementing the `Accepts` and `WriteYaml` methods should be enough. Depending on which type is responsible for serializing the root, the type converter needs to handle either `FirstChildModel` or `MainModel`.